# null check for vetoable delegates in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, delegates, delegation

I need to validate a certain String which a birthdate in YYMMDD format.
The way I did it in my `data class` is:

```
val dateOfBirth: String by Delegates.vetoable(
        text.split("\n")[1].substring(13, 19),
        onChange = { _: KProperty<*>, _: String, newValue: String ->
            "\\d{6}".toRegex().matches(newValue)
        })
```

Basically my class gets instantiate with a certain `text` such as `val clz = MyClass(text = "")`

However, I'm writing some tests and I'm checking what would happen with an empty String `""` and it crashes with

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

which is the line where `text.split("\n")[1].substring(13, 19)` because basically, `text` is empty.

Is there a way in Kotlin to avoid or improve this? In my validation, I'm assuming that the `text` is not empty, but it can be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could simply use `if` to check if string has sufficient length, and depending on business logic assign some default value/raise exception etc...

Something like this:

```
val dateOfBirth: String by Delegates.vetoable(
    if(text.length >= 19)
        text.split("\n")[1].substring(13, 19)
    else // Handle invalid text length
     "" ,
    onChange = { _: KProperty<*>, _: String, newValue: String ->
        "\\d{6}".toRegex().matches(newValue)
    })
```